# Unexpected token Z in JSON at position 0

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-routing

I am working on Angular Application ,

on clicking to button ,

code :

```
 <p> Have account <a routerLink="/login"><button> Login </button></a> </p>
```

I am getting below issue

> Unexpected token Z in JSON at position 0

I am sharing my full code

**signup.html**

```
 <p> Have account <a routerLink="/login"><button> Login </button></a> </p>
```

**app.routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';




const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'login' , component : LoginComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

> **Note**: there is no issue in Incognito window and routing is working correctly , 
>       But in normal window I am facing such problem

Comment: Have you imported the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in the `app.component.html`?

Comment: yes , Just want to tell  there is no issue in Incognito window and routing is working correctly , But in normal window I am facing such problem

Comment: Try after clearing cookies and cache!

Comment: What version of Angular you used? Also, please share the exact error in your post.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale  it worked , please tell why this problem was coming  ?

Comment: @jess   Angular 8 ,  exact error : Unexpected token Z in JSON at position 0

Comment: Not sure but Sometimes your browser cached the previous reposonse,logs,code or you may be installed new library from npm but the latest JS is not available on the browser

Answer (score 0):

It's good that you have fixed your problem.

To support Prashant's answer:

The error you encountered always caused by a server configuration issue, and not by Angular itself. The server is sending an HTML document instead of one of your Javascript files when transpiling occurs. This will explain why clearing cache will fix the error.